# How to interface from Parent Activity to child fragments?

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments

I am using an `ActionBar` to created an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` and 3 `Fragments`. When my Parent Activity is First Created I call a web service and try to return results to the UI of the three separate fragments. So far I have tried adding an Interface to the parent activity and implementing it in the child fragments but i get a null pointer exception. My code is below:

In the parent activity i Declare an interface

```
public interface CommunicateResultsToChilden{
    public void displayResultInfo(JSONObject response);

}
```

And after the HttpGet returns I call:

```
communicateResults.displayResultInfo(response);
```

and then in the child fragment i say

```
public class ChildFrag1 extends Fragment implements CommunicateResultsToChildren{



 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedIstanceState){
                // initialize objects
  }

 public void displayResultInfo(JSONObject response){
       // It never makes it to this call inside the method
       Log.d("RESPONSE", "JSONObject : " + response);
 }

}
```

Before i make the call to `communicateResults.displayResultInfo(response);`

How do i get a reference of this interface i just created?

**SOLUTION**

I added thi inside the

```
protected class CustomViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

   // ....// Methods from tutorial on android developer swipe tabs

   public Fragment getItem(int Position){
                // Each time the view pager calls getItem(position)
                // this is called
                instantiatedFragment(fragment);

    }

}
```

and in my main class

```
 public instantiatedFragment(Fragment fragment){
       if(fragment != null){
               try{
                    // Member Variable instance of CommunicateResultsToChildren
                    newInterface = (CommunicateResultsToChildren) fragment;
                    mInterfaceList.add(newInterface);
                 }catch(Exception ex){
                     // Pop up dialog with exception message
                     // telling user
                 }
       }
 }
```

Comment: can someone please help me? This is the most frustrating thing in the world... right now. Every time i get null pointer exception!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i managed to answer my own question here using http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html and then adding in a method to my `CustomViewPager` inner class that adds the `interface` mentioned above each time i add a `fragment` to the `view pager`. Then inside the main class i keep an `ArrayList<MainActivity.CommunicateResultsToChildren>()` which holds all the interfaces for each child fragment. And  i create a member in the class `communicateResults` which is used in my Callback method from the `HTTPGet` request to call `communicateResults.displayResultsInfo(response)`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Fragment object based on the current position of the `ViewPager` and then simply call `childFrag1.displayResultInfo(response);` and pass the `JSONObject response` in it.

Comment: hmmm yeah, i have seen an example working but porting it to my code is a little difficult. I need to add the interface to each fragment, if the fragment is in view, otherwise i will get a null pointer as well.

Comment: You are already implementing the interface in the Fragments, aren't you?

Comment: I am, but there is no established link, if you will, to the fragments. In other words when i create the fragment in my activity i need to add this interface to the fragments. How do i do this?

Comment: Just a side note i am getting closer when I am done i will post my solution!

Answer (score 0):

You have two way to do this:

- Use event callback to the activity => [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)
- The best way is to use event bus framework like [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) from square.